# ReactJS ensure only owner of object can edit/delete

Tags: reactjs

I do RBAC and authorization on the backend part of the application (NodeJS) and never really bothered about enforcing authorization on the UI as well.

However, let's say I have the following React Router 4 routes:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/books/all" component={BookList} />
    <Route exact path="/books/new" component={BookNew} />
    <Route exact path="/books/:bookId" component={BookDetails} />
    <Route exact path="/books/:bookId/edit" component={BookEdit} />
  </Switch>
```

And I want to make sure that if a logged in user visits a book that is not his, he is not able to render the route `/books/<not my book>/edit`. I am able to do this by implementing a simple check at the `ComponentDidMount()` function:

```
  checkAuthorisation = userId => {
    if (this.props.authenticated._id !== userId) {
      this.props.history.push("/books/all");
    }
  };
```

But I was wondering whether there is a better approach / design pattern of doing it in ReactJS? I was wondering whether removing the `bookId` altogether from the route and just push props like `edit` and `bookId`:

`<Route exact path="/books/edit" component={BookEdit} />`

Comment: I use a similar approach to this:  https://medium.com/better-programming/role-based-authorization-in-react-c70bb7641db4

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do a conditionnal render in your `BookEdit` component (especially if you need to do an async operation to determine authorization).

I would not use a private route here in order to keep the role/auth based routing simple.

In your edit component : check authorization, if false handle this as an error and render an error component (error message and back button, can also be your 404 view), else render your edit component.

To be consistent, you must also make sure you do not have links to this error (conditionnal disabled "Edit" button on the book view if not authorized).

Example (using async check, may not be your case here but this is a general idea) :

```js
class EditComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        loading: true,
        error: null,
        bookProps: null,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const { match, userId } = this.props;
        getBook(match.params.bookId) // request book props
            .then(book => {
                if (book.ownerId !== userId) { // authorization check
                    this.setState({ error: 'Unauthorized', loading: false });
                } else {
                    this.setState({ bookProps: book, loading: false });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({ error: err.message, loading: false });
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { loading, error, bookProps } = this.state;
        if (loading) {
            return <LoadingSpinner />;
        }
        if (error) {
            return <ErrorComponent message={error} />;
        }
        return <BookEditComponent book={bookProps} />;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how I'm currently tackling this. Was wondering if it is widely accepted in the React community.