# How do I ensure only the owner of the object can see the button (ReactJS / NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How do I write code for the frontend that takes visibility logic into consideration, where only the owner of the object can see the button?

In my backend, if the user_id in the comments table matches the user.id in the req object, then the user will have the ability to delete the comment. I've tested this through Postman and it's working ok in the backend.

I'm not sure how to write code in the frontend. Line 4 in the frontend (below) is not correct, but I'm imagining something like this.

**frontend:**

```
function DtcCommentDeleteButton({ comment }) {
  return (
    <span className="FilteredDtcCommentListItem__button">
      {comment.user_id !== req.user.id ? (
        null
      ): (
          <button
            onClick={(e) => this.handleDelete(e)}
            className="FilteredDtcCommentListItem__delete">
          Delete
        </button>
      )}
    </span>
  )
```

**backend:**

```
.delete(requireAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
    const knexInstance = req.app.get("db");
    const comment = await CommentsService.getById(knexInstance, req.params.id);

    if (comment === undefined) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: {
          message: `Comment doesn't exist.`,
        },
      });
    }

    if (comment.user_id !== req.user.id) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: {
          message: `You can only delete your own comments!`,
        },
      });
    }

    CommentsService.deleteComment(knexInstance, req.params.id)
      .then((numRowsAffected) => {
        res.status(204).end();
      })
      .catch(next);
  })
```

**Resources I'm looking into at the moment:**

(1) [ReactJS ensure only owner of object can edit/delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639718/reactjs-ensure-only-owner-of-object-can-edit-delete)

Comment: What exactly is incorrect about what you have?

Comment: @Ace `comment.user_id !== req.user.id` <- For this particular line of code in the frontend, I'm not sure what to write in place of req.user.id.

Comment: Do you not have access to the logged in user's id? Would you not get it from the same place you do when requesting the delete in `handleDelete`?

Comment: @Ace - Check out my solution below for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. In the frontend component, I added the below code block. In the context.js I added the below code block and a few other lines of code:

**Component:**

```
function DtcCommentDeleteButton({ comment, userId, deleteComment, setError }) {
  return (
    <span className="FilteredDtcCommentListItem__span">
      {comment.user_id.id !== parseInt(userId) ? null : (
        <button
          className="FilteredDtcCommentListItem__button"
          onClick={() =>
            handleDeleteComment(comment.id, userId, deleteComment, setError)
          }
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      )}
    </span>
  );
}
```

**Context:**

```
setUser = (payload) => {
  this.setState({ user_id: payload.user_id });
  localStorage.user_id = payload.user_id;
};
```

It's working now. :)